# Excel VBA: Getting the Range Column with last Cell with Data then Offsetting it

Tags: excel, vba

I need a way to get Entire column from J2 to Last Cell with Data but then Offsetting it one column over. Then setting Each cell within that range with formula. Formula has to adjust for each row.

Comment: You are on the right path. Good idea to split you problem into smaller portions. Play around with record macro and look into `offset` ,  `XlDown`, `for loop`. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Edit your question with the code you have tried if you run into problems.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K" & ActiveSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=A2"` Make sure the reference in the formula is relative that you want to iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r1 = Range("J2:J" & N)
    Set r2 = r1.Offset(0, 1)
    r2.Formula = "=J2/100"
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

*(the formula adjusts for each row)*

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you:

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Get the last row of columnn J
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        'Set the range starting from K2 up to last row
        Set rng = .Range("K2:K" & LastRow)
        'Select the range
        rng.Select

    End With

End Sub
```